# Why this struct need more allocated space than just the sizeof itself?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc

I'm kinda new to dynamic memory in C, so far I've managed to understand it better, but I'm trying to allocate memory for this struct, and it should be 24 bytes long, but reserving 24 bytes won't work, I have to allocate 29 bytes or more to make it work, I don't understand the exact reason of this.

I am trying to create a function to initialize tInfection, and I'm allocating memory to tInfection tInfectiousAgent* pointer `object->tInfectiousAgent = (tnfectiousAgent*) malloc(sizeof(tInfectiousAgent));`

[image]

This is the debugger info, as far as I know, malloc returns NULL pointer if isn't able to allocate its data right? but here it doesn't return a NULL pointer.

These are the 2 structs

[image]

[image]

```
tError infection_init(tInfection* object, tInfectiousAgent* infectiousAgent, const char* country,  tDate* date, int cases, int deaths){

    // We check pre conditions
    assert(object != NULL);
    assert(infectiousAgent != NULL);
    assert(country != NULL);
    assert(date != NULL);

    // We allocate memory
    object->infectiousAgent = (tInfectiousAgent*) malloc(sizeof(tInfectiousAgent));
    object->country = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(country) + 1));
    object->date = (tDate*) malloc(sizeof(tDate));


    // We check that memory was allocated correctly
    if ((object->country == NULL) || (object->date == NULL) || (object->infectiousAgent == NULL)) {
            return ERR_MEMORY_ERROR;
    }


    //infectiousAgent_cpy(object->infectiousAgent, infectiousAgent);
    strcpy(object->country, country);
    strcpy(object->date, date);
    object->cases = cases;
    object->deaths = deaths;



    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Explain, please.  In what sense do you think it "should be" 24 bytes long? Is that what `sizeof` actually returns, or your own guess?  Your own guess may be wrong because of alignment and padding.  What do you mean it "won't work"?  What happens exactly?

Comment: Note that bugs which mysteriously go away when you allocate extra memory for something are often caused by buffer overruns or otherwise writing memory that you shouldn't.  This can mean that the bug is in a different part of the code than you think.  A [mcve] would be a good idea.

Comment: Also, as a general note, please copy/paste code into the question instead of using screenshots.  It makes it more possible for people to test your code.

Comment: Hola Iván, welcome to SO. It would be better to include the code in your question instead of screenshots.

Comment: "but here it doesn't return a NULL pointer". That's a good thing isn't it? What exactly is the problem? "won't work" doesn't tell us what specific problem you have.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes sorry, sizeof returns me 24 bytes long, you mean that possibly there's some buffer overflow in other part of the code, and it's just that breaks it there?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: So @NateEldredge, only other malloc/realloc functions can cause this bug, or can be "any" part of the code? tomorrow I'll check it all over again

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're allocating enough space is not the issue here. Provided you use `sizeof`, everything should work fine.

> As an aside, `malloc` doesn't fail if you provide the *wrong* size, since it has no way of knowing what the *right* size is. It can only use what you give it, right *or* wrong. The wrong size will often cause issues down the track if you read or write outside the bounds but that's well after `malloc` has succeeded.

What *is* the potential issue is the values in your debugger for `r0`, `medium` and `date`. The `3.09456111e+35` value for the float `r0` is stored as IEEE754 single precision as the hex bytes `{7a,6e,65,75}` (see [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) for the useful tool that let me discern this). The `medium` variable is `{33,48,20,61}`, and the `date` variable is `{32,4e}`.

If you apply the Intel small-endian adjustments, the byte sequence you end up with is (shown below as a hex dump, including ASCII characters):

```
      +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +0123456789
0000  75 65 6e 7a 61 20 48 33 4e 32  uenza H3N2
```

Given that you're talking about infectious agents, that's almost certain to be a section of the string `Influenza H3N2`, one of the many Influenza strains. Floats, pointers, and other non-string things *may* contain things that look like text but the fact that three consecutive variables have a coherent string across them all, and the fact that the pointer value is not a valid address, ***strongly*** suggest corruption.

That means that you're doing something like copying that string directly into the space where the pointers are meant to be, so probably overflowing some buffer somewhere. One *potential* cause of this may be `strcpy(object->date, date)` unless `tDate` is a type compatible with a C-style string (the definition of `tDate` would go a long way toward figuring out if this is the issue).

This is also supported by your contention that, even though the structure should be 24 bytes long, weird thing happen unless you allocate 29 bytes. That's a clear sign that something is writing beyond where it's supposed to and quite possibly corrupting the memory arena.

I don't know *exactly* the root cause for sure since you haven't provided all the code which would allow us to ascertain that, but it's a pretty good bet based on the evidence that we *can* see.

---

And just one other thing to watch out for, a line like:

```
assert(object != NULL);
```

actually has *no* effect if `NDEBUG` is defined when `assert.h` is included.

Typically, that macro is *not* defined for debug builds but *is* for release builds (although this, of course, depends on your build system).

That means you can't use `assert` as a general purpose contract guard since release builds will convert the `assert` to an empty operation. So, if the assertion can be true or false based on run-time data, `assert` probably isn't a good tool for the job (if it's based only on compile-time data, then you'll catch all the assertions during testing).

Comment: I'm not copying the string at all, I am just trying to allocate memory for that struct type, I updated the code in the main question.

Comment: @Iván: whether you're intentionally copying is not the issue here, people very rarely *intend* to have bugs in their code :-) However, given the content of the variables with values that they really should never have (even by accident), I'd bet money on the fact that you've corrupted it by something like copying too much data, or `strcpy`-ing something that isn't actually a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcpy(object->date, date);
```

is wrong, because `date` is not a string.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.

If you want to copy the object that `date` points to into the space you allocated for `object->date`, you can simply do

```
*object->date = *date;
```

You might also consider whether you really need a copy, or whether it's okay for `object->date` to just point to the same object that `date` already points to.  In that case you can skip the `malloc` for `object->date` and simply do

```
object->date = date;
```